# Как обойти ошибку ValueError при некорректном введенном значении после int(input()) и зациклить ввод?

Tags: python

Допустим есть запрос:
`num = int(input("Введите число"))`

Если в консоль введен не числовой тип данных, возникает ошибка.
Можно через try except продолжить программу. Но не получается у меня зациклить ввод.

Чтобы после ввода некорретных данных, снова отрабатывал `int(input("Введите число"))` до тех пор, пока не будет введено число.

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, поставьте, пожалуйста, галочку, чтобы отметить его как принятый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно вот так (это самый понятный способ, но не самый изящный):

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Введите число: "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    break
```

Здесь мы бесконечно просим пользователя ввести число. Если вылетает исключение, цикл повторяется через `continue`. В противном случае мы выходим из цикла с помощью `break`.

Есть еще один метод. Тут мы не ловим ошибки, а проверяем само число с помощью функции `is_decimal`:

```
while True:
    if input("Введите число: ").is_decimal(): break
    else: continue
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо тебе, добрый человек!)

Comment: @eryomandco если у вас таких вводов несколько - оберните этот цикл в функцию, чтобы не копировать куски кода

Comment: Да, это замечательная идея.

Comment: и чистый `except` лучше никогда не использовать (кроме исследований). `except ValueError` в данном случае

Comment: @n1tr0xs, да, вы правы. Исправил.