# Проверка на пустую строку в целочисленной переменной

Tags: python

у меня есть задачка:

> "Нужно написать программу, которая будет считывать со стандартного
> ввода целочисленные границы промежутка (сначала левая, потом правая,
> каждая на отдельной строке). А дальше будет считывать целые числа со
> стандартного ввода пока не встретит пустую строку, которая будет
> означать конец ввода. Нужно будет проверить входят ли все введенные
> числа в промежуток, проверка включает в себя границы промежутка."

Решаю ее так:

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
while c := int(input()):
    print(a <= c <= b)
```

> У меня появляется ошибка, когда я нажимаю вместо очередного числа,
> enter. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\murik\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\count.py", line 3, in
>
> while c := int(input()):
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Задачу проверяет бот автоматически выдавая ошибку:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File
> "/opt/client/solution/main.py", line 3, in \n    while c :=
> int(input()):\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
> ''\n",

Вот возникает вопрос как сделать проверку что бы целочисленная переменная принимая нажатия enter завершала работу программы.

Comment: сначала проверять на пустую строку, а потом уже переводить в число, если строка не пуста. Или ловить исключение и там уже проверять на пустую строку. PS. В питоне нет никаких целочисленных переменных.

Comment: Как нету, если вот выше в коде я обозначил ее как int. иначе бы сравнивалась значение как строки, а мне надо как числа.

Comment: У вас нигде нет проверки, что через input не пустая строка введена, сразу пытаетесь в int преобразовать.

Comment: См. [Как обойти ошибку ValueError при некорректном введенном значении после int(input()) и зациклить ввод?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1544022/1365)

Comment: это не "обозначил, как int", это "попросил питон перевести строку в целое число". И в случае пустой строки питон говорит, что сорян, не могу. В питоне у переменных нет типа.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку помогла. и за объяснения.